# accessing form elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, child-nodes

im coding a form with dynamic textfield adding but i cant get num of the elements and their content created dynamically

here is the sample

```
<input name="mobiles[]" id="mobile"><a onclick="addfield()">add</a>
```

im using appenchild method for adding new inputs

for accessing mobiles elements i use

```
document.getElementsByName('mobiles[]').length;
```

but it returns just 1 and dont count added fields

Comment: um, show the code....

Comment: function addfield(args){ var x = document.createElement("li");
 y=document.createElement("input");
 document.getElementById(args).appendChild(x);
/////////////////////ADD Mobiles/////////////////////////// 
 mobileCounter++;
 var idcounter="mobile" + mobileCounter;

 x.innerHTML="<input type=\"text\" id=\""+idcounter+"\" onblur=\"mobilecheck('"+idcounter+"')\" class=\"txtfield\">";
}

Comment: .the code is too long . witch part of the code do u need?

Comment: Where is the name attribute?

Comment: oh thanks i just see that in js cod i didnt put the name attribute. thats why my cod didnt work. thanks again

Comment: and it does not have the name which you are using to loop it up....

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are appending the input fields is wrong. Check the snippet below, and try running it. Hope this helps.

```js
addField = function(){
  var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.name = 'mobiles[]';
  
  li.append(input);
  wrapper.append(li);
};

updateCount = function(){
  // Shows you current count on the page.
  count = document.getElementsByName('mobiles[]').length;
  document.getElementById('count-wrapper').innerHTML = count;
};
```

```html
<ul id="wrapper">
  <li><input name="mobiles[]"></li>
</ul>

<button onclick="addField()">Add Input</button>
<button onclick="updateCount()">Update Count</button>

<div>
  Input Field Count is : <span id="count-wrapper">1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for help.i have found that i didnt set name attribute in appendchild code. its working now